# Python: How to call rest endpoint and not wait for it to finish (fire and forget)?

Tags: python, rest, background-process

I have a data collector python script that is started each minute by cron, gets some data and puts it into the database.

At its end, data collector should post last row id to a processing rest endpoint under my control and exit.
Data collector script shouldn't wait for processing to finish, so whatever happens in data processor shouldn't influence data collector by any means.
Data collector script don't need any response from rest endpoint.

Upon calling, processing endpoint will retrieve data from the database and do its work.
Processing could eventually take more than a minute to finish, but more often in less than 30 seconds.

How to call rest endpoint and not wait for it to finish?

Comment: Do you mean to run this async?

Comment: Have you considered multithreading ?

Comment: I know this isn't a direct answer, but I'd recommend system design change. If processing takes 30 seconds (or more), I'd recommend posting row IDs from your data collector to a queue, then have workers pull from the queue and do processing. That way your script runs quickly without needing to wait for processing to finish AND you can scale your processing infrastructure horizontally by spinning up more workers.

Comment: my last comment is going on a lot of assumptions about your system so please disregard if there are reasons not listed in the question that make this an infeasible idea

Comment: @kingkupps, you are perfectly right, something like message broker would fit in nicely in this scenario, but for two simple scripts/project it would be an overkill.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen, yes script is async, but that doesn't change anything. Even if you call something asynchronously, you have to await for it to finish.

Comment: @ArthurKing, the same goes to multithreading. It doesn't solve my problem. You have to wait until thread finishes.
Processing must wait for data collection to finish, so you cannot run processes in parallel.

Comment: Let's say one approach could be to create a communication file when data processor finishes and than to check for file existence in data processor, but that is a very ugly solution. Instead of file, it could be a record in table... I wander if there is another approach maybe.

Comment: If you really just want to send bytes over the wire somewhere and not wait for the response, you might have luck [using sockets directly](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html). It's a bit lower level and you won't get much for free but it should do what you want.

Comment: Now, when I read your response, I must admit that it sounds silly. So far the best fit would be a message broker, but it is kind of too complex for a single use case requirement. Maybe to implement async queue. When rest gets called, I could put parameters in the async queue and provide response back. Queue could be connected to some listener that will start processing.

Comment: I have just read my previous answer and I am laughing. When I said "Now, when I read your response, I must admit that it sounds silly." I meant, that my request sounds sill, not your answer. Sorry for potential misunderstanding. What you have said is perfectly fine.

Comment: No worries I understood you :) hopefully this was helpful